# Android notification icon cannot display off

Tags: android, notifications

I wrote some Android codes to display on and off an icon. However, after run the codes, the icon can display but not disappear (display off). It is always on the notification bar. If possible, could you help me have a look. THX

```
 final Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        final NotificationManager mNotifyManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                        Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final int mNotifyId = 1;
        final String TITLE = "abc";
        final String MSG = "abc is active.";


    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_notification);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(TITLE)
                    .setContentText(MSG)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_dark)
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setAutoCancel(false);


        final Handler handler= new Handler();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mNotifyManager.notify(mNotifyId, mBuilder.build());
                mNotifyManager.cancel(mNotifyId);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Comment: Why are you showing and just then cancel a notification?

Comment: Just for testing .... but I do not know why it cannot be cancelled

Comment: Cancel should work. Could you post your builder?

Comment: Sure, I added them. THX

Comment: Hmm everything looks ok... (Thinking...)

Comment: I would start with a simpler notification. Removing large icon and ongoing. Also doing the test once, not using the handler. Just for testing and discard things...

Comment: Where are you executing this code? In your onCreate ()?

Comment: I have not tried your code, and I am not quite clear about the problem you are experiencing, but have you tried `setAutoCancel(true)`? or maybe add `setOngoing(false)'?